# Nested Attributes for Multiple Insertion Using check_box on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, nested-attributes

Hi guys I have a problem from my project. I have two tables/models (many to many), the first one is Product:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :categories, :through => :product_category_rels
has_many :product_category_rels, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_category_rels
end
```

the second one is Category:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :products, :through => :product_category_rels
has_many :product_category_rels
end
```

and of course a relation's table, Product_Category_Rel:

```
class ProductCategoryRel < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :category
end
```

I wanna insert data of product with many categories using check_box, so the system can insert a row of data to Product and multiple rows to Product_Category_Rel as Category's Indexes.

here we go my code!

view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
   <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this product from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
   <% end %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :price %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :price %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :stock %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :stock %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :description %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
      <%= f.collection_select :user_id, @users, :id, :username %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
      <% @category.each do |category| %>
      <%= f.fields_for :product_category_rels do |ff| %>  
          <%= ff.check_box :category_id, {}, category.id %>
          <%= category.name %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %><%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
</html>
```

controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @product = Product.select('products.*, categories.name as catname, users.username as username').joins(:categories).joins(:user)
    end
    def create
        @product = Product.create(product_params)
        if @product.save
            redirect_to products_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
    def new
        @product = Product.new
        @product_category_rels = @product.product_category_rels.build
        @category = Category.all
        @users = User.order(:username)
    end
    def edit        
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])    
        @category = Category.all
        @users = User.order(:username)
    end
    def update
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
        if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
            redirect_to products_path
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
    def destroy
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
        @product.destroy
        redirect_to products_path   
    end
    private
      def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :stock, :description, :user_id,
            :product_category_rels_attributes => [:product_id, :category_id])
      end
end
```

=======================

Updated, I can insert multiple categories to product but it's array! for example:

I select the first one category:

```
product.id = 1
product.name = Naruto
product.category_id = [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

0 for unselected checkboxes! if I select two categories, I will get:

```
product.id = 1
product.name = Naruto
product.category_id = [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

and

```
product.id = 2
product.name = Naruto
product.category_id = [0, 1, 0, 0]
```

LOL

Comment: You have to comment `raise params.inspect`.It is used to see what params are being passed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Updated! Please see the params. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple_form gem [https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple%5fform)

```
gem 'simple_form'
```

so, all you have to do is:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@product)%>
  <%= f.input :name%>
  <%= f.input :price%>
  <%= f.input :stock%>
  <%= f.input :description%>
  <%= f.input :user_id, collection: @users.map {|u| [u.username, u.id] %>
  <%= f.association :category, as: :check_boxes%>
  <%= f.button :submit%>
<% end %>
```

add this to your controller(to the **new** action i guess) `@users = User.order(:username)`

ps you also have wrong create action. You should have `@product = Product.new(product_params)`